# Label that counts when button is pushed doesn't work in WPF following MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm a C# newbie and I'm trying to make a simple program that has two buttons and a label. Buttons are "up" and "down", and the number in the label changes according to them. When I execute the program, label shows the initial value which defined in viewmodel. But when I push buttons, it doesn't update the value. I couldn't figure out which is not working, buttons or label when an update occurs. Thanks for your time.

I think the problem is the usage "RaisePropertyChanged". I have no idea how should I use it. If someone explains it, it would be good.

Buttons and Label in view:

```
<Button x:Name="Up" Content="Up" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1"                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Command="{Binding UpCommand}"/>
<Button x:Name="Down" Content="Down" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"  Command="{Binding DownCommand}" />
<Label x:Name="Number" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="31" Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="161" Content="{Binding Path=Lol, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="#FFB95151" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Column="1"  />
```

this is ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel : BaseINPC
{
    //Number class to hold the number
   private Number lol; //I'm not good at naming
   public Number Lol
   {
       get
       {
           return lol;
       }
       set
       {
           lol = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged("Lol");
       }
   }


    public MainViewModel()
    {
        lol = new Number { number = 5 }; //initial value
        RaisePropertyChanged("Lol");
    }

    #region Commands
    //Up botton commands
    void UpNumber()
    {
        lol.change(true); //it adds 1 to number when True, substracts 1 when false
        RaisePropertyChanged("Lol");
    }

    bool CanUpNumber()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public DelegateCommand UpCommand { get { return new DelegateCommand(UpNumber, CanUpNumber); }                }
    //Down button
    void DownNumber()
    {
        lol.change(false);
        RaisePropertyChanged("Lol");
    }

    bool CanDownNumber()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public DelegateCommand DownCommand { get { return new DelegateCommand(DownNumber, CanDownNumber); } }


    #endregion
  }
```

This is in my Model :

```
 class Number : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _number;

    public int number
    {
        get { return _number; }
        set
        {
            _number = value;
        }
    }


    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public void change(bool up)
    {
        if (up)
            _number++;
        else
            _number--;

    }


    public override String ToString()
    {
        return "" + _number;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion


}
```

Comment: When you debug your solution and you click the button, can you see that the value is being changed?

Comment: I don't know how to use the debugger in Visual. Just started to learn it yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your Number class

```
public void change(bool up)
{
    if (up)
        _number++;
    else
        _number--;
    RaisePropertyChanged("number");
}
```

or

```
public int number
{
    get { return _number; }
    set
    {
        _number = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("number");
    }
}

public void change(bool up)
{
    if (up)
        number++;
    else
        number--;
}
```

you were missing notification for the number property

also change the content binding of Label to `Content="{Binding Path=Lol.number}"` since number is the real property which actually change when method change() is executed.

Lol may not necessary to be notified if not changing while runtime, also UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged is unrelevant with binding to label so perhaps remove that too.

Comment: Lol is changing while runtime. I tried to hold the number that I show in Lol and buttons are making it bigger or smaller. I made the changes you commend, but the number is not changing.

Comment: change binding of label to `Content="{Binding Path=Lol.number}"` this will work I missed in first look

Comment: It worked! Can you explain why did it worked? Thanks.

Comment: You may remove `ToString()` from your number class, as that was one of the reason you can not find the error easily. secondly the property Lol is assigned only once, rest of the time only value of number is changed

Comment: The reason it did not worked because the label was binded to Lol property which was not actually changing but the property number was changing when you execute change method. and binding will not update its value unless the value of property changes. so we bind it to the correct property which is supposed to be changed and it begin to work.